# Setting a layout of elements on a page

Tags: context

I am new on ConTEXt and I am trying to setup a layout of elements on a page. Basicly, what I want is to put some figures and tables in specific places on a page. Bellow is a sketch of a typical layout that I want.

[image: Layout of some elements on a page]

How can I do that? I've try a lot of ideas but none have worked

**EDITED**

In latex I can easily get this layout using minipages. For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,nohead}
\setlength\parindent{0cm}

\begin{document}

\fbox{
 \begin{minipage}{.75\textwidth}
  \fbox{
   \begin{minipage}{.1\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../card.png}
   \end{minipage}
  }
  \fbox{
   \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
     \centering
     Lorem Ipsum

     Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem
   \end{minipage}
  }
 \fbox{
  \begin{minipage}{.95\textwidth}
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras luctus     augue augue, vitae vulputate ligula mattis vel. Praesent efficitur massa et neque vehicula, quis ultricies mi vestibulum. Donec facilisis, nibh eu mollis consectetur, justo elit faucibus leo, ut viverra dolor ante sit amet lorem
  \end{minipage}
}
 \end{minipage}
}
\fbox{
 \begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
 \begin{tabular}{c|c}
   Lorem & Ipsum\\ \hline
   Lorem & Ipsum\\ \hline
   Lorem & Ipsum\\ \hline
   Lorem & Ipsum\\ \hline
   Lorem & Ipsum\\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
}

\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras luctus augue augue, vitae vulputate ligula mattis vel. Praesent efficitur massa et neque vehicula, quis ultricies mi vestibulum. Donec facilisis, nibh eu mollis consectetur, justo elit faucibus leo, ut viverra dolor ante sit amet lorem
\end{minipage}
}

\end{document}
```

Which produce:

[image]

So, my question is: Is there any way to emulate this layout, using context, so that my layout adjust automaticly, as in the latex example?

Comment: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Layers

Comment: It will take some time to read and test, but meanwhile I'd like to answer one thing: Aren't layers an absolute position methods? What happens if the elements grow or shrink? The layout will not adjust correctly, isn't it. There is any method that works something like de `div` in HTML, that autoadjust as content are added? (sorry if this is a silly question)

Comment: Yes, of course, the layout will not auto-adjust.  In that case you should have a look at [Column Sets](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/columns.pdf) although a complex layout as you show it might be hard to achieve.  (It's also not very reader friendly.)

Comment: @HenriMenke I was trying to achieve something in contex as I can do in latex, using minipages (see my edit for clarification). This is not an awful layout, it just depends on context. For example, I was thinking a layout for test application, where I can put a table of grades, a logotype, an Institution name, and so on

Comment: That is actually rather easy.  See the updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LaTeX has `\fbox` and `minipage`.  ConTeXt has (the much more powerful) `\framed` (and its companion `\start...\stopframed`).  You have to set `align=normal` to obtain regular linebreaking.

```
\setupframed[offset=5pt]

\starttext

\noindent % leave vertical mode
\startframed[align=normal,width=.75\textwidth,location=lohi]
  \externalfigure[cow][width=.1\hsize,frame=on,location=lohi]
  \startframed[align=middle,width=.8\hsize,location=lohi]
    Lorem Ipsum

    Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem
  \stopframed

  \startframed[align=normal,width=.95\hsize]
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras
    luctus augue augue, vitae vulputate ligula mattis vel. Praesent
    efficitur massa et neque vehicula, quis ultricies mi
    vestibulum. Donec facilisis, nibh eu mollis consectetur, justo
    elit faucibus leo, ut viverra dolor ante sit amet lorem
  \stopframed
\stopframed
\quad
\startframed[align=normal,width=.2\textwidth,location=lohi]
  \starttabulate[|c|c|]
    \NC Lorem \NC Ipsum \NC\NR\HL
    \NC Lorem \NC Ipsum \NC\NR\HL
    \NC Lorem \NC Ipsum \NC\NR\HL
    \NC Lorem \NC Ipsum \NC\NR\HL
    \NC Lorem \NC Ipsum \NC\NR\HL
  \stoptabulate
\stopframed
\par\noindent
\startframed[align=normal,width=\textwidth]
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras luctus
  augue augue, vitae vulputate ligula mattis vel. Praesent efficitur
  massa et neque vehicula, quis ultricies mi vestibulum. Donec
  facilisis, nibh eu mollis consectetur, justo elit faucibus leo, ut
  viverra dolor ante sit amet lorem
\stopframed

\stoptext
```

[image]

---

The below looks quite awful but should give you a good idea of how to position things absolutely on the page.

```
\starttext

\definelayer[overlay]

\setlayerframed
  [overlay]
  [x=3cm,y=1cm,width=7cm]
  {Lorem ipsum}

\setlayerframed
  [overlay]
  [x=11cm,y=0cm,width=4cm]
  [align=normal,width=4cm]
  {\starttabulate[|r|l|]
     \HL
     \NC c \NC centered      \NC \AR
     \NC l \NC left aligned  \NC \AR
     \NC r \NC right aligned \NC \AR
     \HL
   \stoptabulate
   \blank
   \input ward\par}

\setlayerframed
  [overlay]
  [x=0cm,y=3cm,width=10cm]
  [align=normal,width=10cm]
  {\input zapf\par}

\setlayerframed
  [overlay]
  [x=0cm,y=10cm,width=\textwidth]
  [align=normal,width=\textwidth]
  {\input knuth\par}

\setlayer
  [overlay]
  [x=0cm,y=0cm,width=2cm,height=2cm]
  {\externalfigure[cow][width=2cm]}

\flushlayer[overlay]

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly. I just figured this a bit sooner when I realized that you need to setup `align` parameter to diferentiate between a hbox and a vbox :D Thanks so much. Please, does not erase the layer content. It is just a nice example how to use it

Comment: By the way, what means `location=lohi`?

Comment: @Amadeus Vertical center, see http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Framed#Location_parameter